# How do I restart tweens in DOTween and Unity?

Tags: unity, tweening

I am trying to restart a couple of tweens when I load a new scene. So far,
I have this in MainMenuController.cs :

```
void Start () {
    if (currentScene.name == "MainMenuScene") {
        Debug.Log("In current scene");
        tweenList[0] = mainMenuText.transform.DOShakePosition(5, 10)
                                   .SetAutoKill(false).SetRecyclable(true);
        tweenList[1] = playGameButton.transform.DOShakePosition(5, 10)
                                     .SetAutoKill(false).SetRecyclable(true);
        tweenList[2] = exitGameButton.transform.DOShakePosition(5, 10)
                                     .SetAutoKill(false).SetRecyclable(true);
        DOTween.RestartAll(false);
    }

}
```

However, this does not start when I reload the scene using

```
public void ExitToMainMenu() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenuScene");
    }
```

The above is called from another script.
Is there some way to restart my tweens when the scene is loaded again?

Comment: Is the object that contains MainMenuController preserved between scenes (using DontDestroyOnLoad)?

Comment: Yes, I did that too. But the Tween still doesn't start up. What can I do differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call these:

```
SetAutoKill(false)
SetRecyclable(true);
```

Don't mess with `DOTween's` settings unless you know what you're doing! :)

Also, don't call `Start()` from another script. `Start()` is for `Unity`, not for you :D. Make another method like `StartTweens()` and do:

```
public void StartTweens(){

    if (currentScene.name == "MainMenuScene") {
            Debug.Log("In current scene");

            foreach(Tweener tw in tweenList)
                tw.DOKill(); // or tw.Kill();

            tweenList[0] = mainMenuText.transform.DOShakePosition(5, 10);                    
            tweenList[1] = playGameButton.transform.DOShakePosition(5, 10);   
            tweenList[2] = exitGameButton.transform.DOShakePosition(5, 10);

    }
}
```

Then call `StartTweens()` in `Start()`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked splendidly! Do you know why this works and not my implementation, though?

Comment: My guess is that you set `SetAutoKill(false)` and the tweens were not killed (even if they were finished). Then, without killing them, you assigned new ones and it got messed up. I'd leave the `DOTween` settings as they are. These settings are for optimization :) Also, you could kill the tweens (with this foreach loop) in the `OnDestroy()` method from `MonoBehavior` so when the scene finishes, they'll get destroyed immediately :) You can read about the method here: `https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html`

Comment: Ah! I see what went wrong now. Thanks for the help @Spectre!

Comment: No prob! Remember to upvote answers you find helpful :)